# Adding an attribute to a property of a dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamic-programming, expandoobject

I want to create a dynamic object based in other object's properties and attributes, but I don't know neither how to add attributes to my dynamic properties, nor how to get them back.
Is that possible?

Here is my code, but it's not working. Thanks!

```
var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;
var props = typeof(Costumer).GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var customAttributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    var displayAttr = customAttributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>();
    expando.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(expando[prop.Name],displayAttr.SingleOrDefault());
    var getAttribute = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(expando[prop.Name]);
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error, or do you not get the expected result but something else? If an error, at which line?

Comment: The AddAttributes Method should add the DisplayAttribute which belongs to a Costumer property to the dynamic property created in my ExpandoObject but it doesn't happen, it just puts the attribute inside the Type that came by the PropertyType added into the object.